# Accessing Twitter Without User Interaction

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I'm writing some scripts for my boss that reads a specific user's tweets over the course of a week, and then dumps them into a formatted Tumblr post. Because he wants this done automated, I'm using cron to run the scripts periodically, but this is not the point of the post.

My question is, since the move to OAuth by the Twitter API, is user interaction necessary to get credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not if you can get your application approved for [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) by Twitter.

Comment: It is not user free. You still have to provide valid credentials for an existing account. But the user does not have to explicitly grant access to the application that uses xAuth. You just have to provide username and password in exchange for a xAuth/OAuth token. Check the documentation link I've provided above. And don't forget: You have to mail Twitter to grant xAuth to your application. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I emailed them, but I doubt I'll get approved. :(